# About Blocks and how to use them

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks, controllers

First of all, I'm pretty new with Magento, so I'm still in the very beginning of my learning process.

I had the following controller:

```
class Chromo_SimpleContact_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // get current layout
        $this->loadLayout();
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
            'chromo.simple_contact',
            array(
                'template' => 'chromo/simple_contact.phtml'
            )
        );

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function sendemailAction()
    {
        // get all the parameters from the form
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        // create a new object Zend_Email
        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setBodyText($params['comment']);
        $mail->setFrom($params['email'], $params['name']);
        $mail->addTo('testemail@testemail.com', 'Test Email');
        $mail->setSubject($params['subject']);

        try{
           $mail->send();
        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email');
        }

        $this->_redirect('chromo-simplecontact/');
    }
}
```

So, this controller is in charge of everything, I mean, it is creating the Block on the run. I wanted to change this (because in the future I want to use Ajax, and yes, that'll be another question) in order to separate my block.

To achieve this I created my block:

```
class Chromo_SimpleContact_Block_ContactBlock extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    public function customBlockAction()
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('chromo/simple_contact.phtml');

        // use the instance's public rendering method to obtain the block's
        // output and assign it to the response object
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
    }
}
```

y declared it in the config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Chromo_SimpleContact>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Chromo_SimpleContact>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <contactBlock>
                <class>Chromo_SimpleContact_Block_ContactBlock</class>
            </contactBlock>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <SimpleContactRouter>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Chromo_SimpleContact</module>
                    <frontName>aboutus</frontName>
                </args>
            </SimpleContactRouter>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Chromo_SimpleContact>
                    <file>simplecontact.xml</file>
                </Chromo_SimpleContact>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and modified the controller:

```
class Chromo_SimpleContact_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // get current layout
        $this->loadLayout();

        $this->createBlock('SimpleContact/ContactBlock');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function sendemailAction()
    {
        // get all the parameters from the form
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        // create a new object Zend_Email
        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setBodyText($params['comment']);
        $mail->setFrom($params['email'], $params['name']);
        $mail->addTo('sebastian@all4cellular.com', 'Sebastian Test Email');
        $mail->setSubject($params['subject']);

        try{
           $mail->send();
        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email');
        }

        $this->_redirect('chromo-simplecontact/');
    }
}
```

and this is the module declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Chromo_SimpleContact>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Chromo_SimpleContact>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Finally the simplecontact.xml which is in frontend/chromo/default/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/chromo_style.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>

</layout>
```

When I had it creating the block "on the run" it was working, but now that I'm trying to define the block separately is not working.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you have a file simplecontact.xml?

Comment: yes I do, I'll add it to the question right now

Comment: You posted the Chromo_SimpleContact.xml from modules... I was asking for the layout file, but I answered and I think you can see the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Tre problem is with your blocks class node from the config.xml

```
<contactBlock>
    <class>Chromo_SimpleContact_Block_ContactBlock</class>
</contactBlock>
```

And then you call it like this:

```
$this->createBlock('SimpleContact/ContactBlock');
```

You should have

```
<SimpleContact>
    <class>Chromo_SimpleContact_Block</class>
</SimpleContact>
```

And to call it, you either use the layout file simplecontact.xml as descirbed in the wiki http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates or as you did it in the controller, you should have:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('SimpleContact/ContactBlock')->toHtml()
```

You should also change the _contruct() method from the block and add:

```
$this->setTemplate('chromo/simple_contact.phtml');
```

That method you have there customBlockAction is not usable.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that part. How should I call it? Because after fixing what you said the following error appeared:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Chromo_SimpleContact_IndexController::createBlock() in /home2/chromo/public_html/app/code/local/Chromo/SimpleContact/controllers/IndexController.php on line 15

Comment: I changed the call to
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('SimpleContact/ContactBlock');
but nothing, now its empty. It loads the header and the footer but the content is empty

Comment: Yes, that's the right call, but it's not used ok, but you still didn't post what you have in the layout xml file - should be under design/frontend/theme/theme/layout/simplecontact.xml

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize I posted the wrong one, I edited and posted the right one. Should I reference the block in simplecontact.xml?

Comment: The layout file you added will set the page to 1column, but will not set the template for the block. You can either set it there by adding the route nodes to your action and do an update on the handle you want (content) or you set it in the block class inside the construct method.

Comment: I added into config.xml: <Chromo_SimpleContact>
                <reference name="content">
                    <block type="simplecontact/contactblock" name="simplecontact" template="simplecontact/simple_contact.phtml" />
                </reference>
            </Chromo_SimpleContact>
But it didn't work. Is it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you used the createBlock with the correct parameters: `$type`, `$name`, `$attributes` as follows.

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
    'chromo.simple_contact',
    array(
        'template' => 'chromo/simple_contact.phtml'
    )
);
```

But in your block you only pass the block a template, but you should also pass it the type and a name as before.

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('chromo/simple_contact.phtml');
```

Then in your controller you are calling a createBlock function that does not exist and also passing it the wrong variable as you have defined your blocks as `contactBlock` in your xml:

```
$this->createBlock('SimpleContact/ContactBlock');
```

But since you have a layout xml in your module anyway what I would suggest your be to use this to add the blocks. You firstly need to find out the layout handle of your page. An easy way of doing this is to visit the url of your page and see what classes are set against the body tag. These classes are your layout handles but with `-` and not `_`.

Take this layout handle and replace the `-` with `_`, then you can add the following to your layout xml:

```
<your_layout_handle>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="chromo.simple_contact" template="chromo/simple_contact.phtml" />
    </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

Then you will be able to display this block using `$this->getChildHtml('chromo.simple_contact')`

In this case you could remove your block as it is not needed, and clean up your controller.